# Measuring the current of a Wheatstone Bridge, given four known resistances and supply voltage

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

Say I had a Wheatstone Bridge with four known resistances and a supply voltage.

How would I go about getting the current across Vg?

[image: bridgeexample]

I understand how to get the voltage Vg using Ohm's Law and Kirchoff's first rule, but am confused as to how I'd go about getting Ig.

Thanks!

Comment: Pay attention: a current is not *across* but *through* an element. This is not just a language issue.

Comment: If your voltage measurement device has a high input impedence like most DMMs there will be very very very little current through it, in this sense you can discard it. Do you mean Ig as in current through the wheatstone bridge?

Comment: What is the element labeled Vg? Is it a voltmeter, or another impedance? An ideal voltmeter has infinite impedance, so the current through the Vg element would be 0.

Comment: If the voltmeter were to have infinite impedance, you're saying the current would always be 0? Even if the bridge was unbalanced?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if Vg represents an open circuit or a resistive load of some kind.

1. If it's an open circuit, then you have the trivial case: there is no current and \$I_{g}=0\$. This case might be useful if you have voltage probes hooked up to nodes D and B.
2. If there is a resistive load, then you must have prior knowledge of the load's resistance, \$R_{g}\$, to calculate the current. Knowing \$V_{g}\$ and \$R_{g}\$, you have enough information to use Ohm's Law to solve for \$I_{g}\$.

A common classroom experiment with a Wheatstone bridge is to put a light bulb  between nodes D and B. When there is an imbalance in the bridge, current will flow between D and B the light bulb will light up. R2 is adjusted until the light goes out, indicating that the bridge is balanced and D and B are at the same potential. How much current is going through the bulb depends entirely on the properties of the bulb itself.